# Building PocketSphinx for PiHueSphinx for Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, swig

I am trying to get this source building:

https://github.com/garuma/PiHueSphinx

I have pulled the master branch for the above repo and the PocketSphinx repo mentioned:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx

I failed to get the pocketsphinx code to build on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015 with 68 build errors, starting with the following error:

```
cannot open source file "sphinxbase/err.h"  pocketsphinx    c:\git\pocketsphinx\src\libpocketsphinx\vector.c    76
```

So I decided to download the latest build of `sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx` from:

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/download/

After that, following the `Building` section in the PiHueSphinx `README.md`, I tried to get the PiHueSphinx solution to build (again, Win7 VS15). I restored the NuGet packages, updated the NuGet packages, rebuilt the PiHueSphinx project and then fixed the code on line 31 of HueController.cs:

Replace: `var client = new LocalHueClient (ip);`

With: `var client = new LocalHueClient (ip.IpAddress);`

I now get the following build error:

```
The command "gcc -Wall -ggdb -shared -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -L/usr/local/lib -lpocketsphinx -lsphinxad -lsphinxbase -o bin\Debug\libsphinx_hue_detection.so sphinx_hue_detection.c" exited with code 9009.  PiHueSphinx C:\git\PiHueSphinx\PiHueSphinx\PiHueSphinx.csproj   97
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I think I should be providing references to the Sphinx libraries from the `PiHueSphinx.csproj` file (as mentioned in the readme) but simply replacing the paths beginning `/usr/local/` with paths to the downloaded and extracted sphinxbase and pocketsphinx folders results in the same message, but with the modified paths.

How can I get this solution to build?

(Perhaps a better question is: How can I get a C# console application to build using the Sphinx libraries, but I don't want to push my luck or get off topic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the code on the github repos were not good for building, so downloaded the latest `sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx`, decompressed and built the source from here:

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/download/